# Nuxt - quit the lifecycle on redirect?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

I have a Nuxt project running without server-side rendering i.e. entirely client-side only.

A middleware script queries a remote API to see whether the user must re-login. If so, a redirect to the login page is fired:

**/middleware/checkLogin.js:**

```
import {apiReq} from '~/assets/js/utils'

export default async ctx => {

    let privateRoute = ctx.store.state.privateRoutes.includes(ctx.route.name);

    //is logout request - nothing check required
    if (ctx.route.name == 'index' && ctx.route.query.logout) return;

    //check login and react accordingly
    let res = await apiReq.call(ctx, 'checkLogin');
    if (res === null) return;
    privateRoute && !res.data.result && redir('/?promptLogin=1');
    !privateRoute && res.data.result && redir('/animals');
}

const redir = route => onNuxtReady(() => $nuxt.$router.push(route));
```

The issue I've got is that despite the redirect, the lifecycle is continuing on to load the page (the one the user shouldn't be able to access) including its `asyncData` etc.

**pages/somePrivatePage.vue**

```
export default {
    asyncData() {
        //this still runs, even if middleware logged a redirect
    }
}
```

**Desired result**: when the redirect is logged, subsequent lifecycle steps don't run.

Is there any way I can achieve this? I could log something in state from middleware, and use that as a condition in the `asyncData` so it doesn't execute, but that seems hacky.

**/middleware/checkLogin.js**

```
if (privateRoute && !res.data.result) {
    ctx.store.commit('dontDoStuff', 1);
    redir('/?promptLogin=1');
}
```

**/pages/somePage.vue**

```
asyncData({store}) {
    if (store.state.dontDoStuff) return;
    //then this won't run...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the middleware is using `$nuxt.$router.push`, which just pushes a new route instead of redirecting.

The Nuxt context includes a [`redirect` function](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context#redirect) that should be used for redirection:

```js
// middleware/checkLogin.js
export default async ctx => {
  ⋮                                           
  privateRoute && !res.data.result && ctx.redirect('/?promptLogin=1')
  !privateRoute && res.data.result && ctx.redirect('/animals')
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-middleware-redirect-3cbzr5?file=middleware%2FcheckLogin.js)

Comment: Thanks - and indeed, but `redirect()` isn't available on the client, according to [the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/#redirect).

Comment: @Mitya That only applies to **Nuxt plugins** client-side. MIddleware are not plugins. See updated demo that shows middleware in a Nuxt static site, where `context.redirect` exists.

Comment: Oh - that's interesting. I'll try that, then.

Comment: nice use of emojis xD